# How can I turn a list of values to a list of dictionaries with the same key added to each value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Let's say I have this list of IDs/values:

```
Input:

['aaa','bbb','ccc']
```

I've been stuck on figuring out how I could get the following list of dictionaries. Each dictionary contain the key "id" paired with each of the IDs/values from the list.

```
Desired Output:

[{'id': 'aaa'}, {'id': 'bbb'}, '{id': 'ccc'}]
```

Comment: [{"id": i } for i in ['aaa','bbb','ccc']]

Answer (score 3):

You can create a list of dictionaries with a list comprehension:

```
list_ = ['aaa','bbb','ccc']
output = [{'id': elem} for elem in list_]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use list slicing concepts here to get your result.

```
list1 = ['aaa','bbb','ccc']
finalOutput = [{'id': value} for value in list1]
```

Comment: This isn't "list slicing". It's a **list comprehension** that creates a list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

you can loop and append those dictionaries to list like this:

```
some_list = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
dictionary_list = []

for i in some_list:
    dictionary_list.append({'id': i})
```

You will get a list like you wanted.